# why browser show an empty screen when i start PHP test-script in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

i updated Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 16.04 on my testserver to get compatible with my ISP's server.

My configuration as shown in phpMyAdmin, **which runs fine**!:

- **Server**: Localhost via UNIX socket
- **Server type**: MySQL
- **Server version**: 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
- **Protocol version**: 10
- **User**: root@localhost
- **Server charset**: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
- **Apache**/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- **Database client version**: libmysql - **mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407**
- **PHP extensio**n: mysqli Documentation
- **PHP version**: 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

My test-script below create an empty screen in web-browser:

```php
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "cydb4tsa", "RedGround");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}else{ echo "connected"; }
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

i found no relevant error-message in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

**mysql runs on the command line including all queries from imported tables:**

```
sebu@sebu-Inspiron-3437:~$ mysql -u root -p<pw> RedGround

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

**apache2 runs**, browser show default page  and

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ | grep php
php7.0.conf
php7.0.load
```

**php7 runs**,  browser show all infos

**phpMyAdmin runs normally** although an error is displayed:
**Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed**.

still get empty screen, when i run above php-script.
Maybe a communication-error between mysql and php?

```
sebu@sebu-Inspiron-3437:~$ php -m

[PHP Modules]
calendar Core ctype date dom exif fileinfo filter ftp gd gettext hash
iconv json libxml mbstring mcrypt mysqli mysqlnd openssl pcntl pcre PDO
pdo_mysql Phar posix readline Reflection session shmop SimpleXML sockets SPL 
standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlwriter xsl
Zend OPcache zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

screen of my project after update on my lap, localhost:
[image]
screen of my project online onISP-server:
[image]

Comment: Maybe some PHP module is missing or is not enabled. What is the output of `php -m`?

Comment: Add these lines just after your `<?php` tag to display errors then try again:
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: screen is still empty with this,  however when i force an error by changing db-name , error  Unknown database 'RedGroun' is shown, it seems mysqli_connect_errno() is cause for error

Comment: info: after update ubuntu, i had to update Ubuntu kernel 2 times and also uptates for this machine.

Comment: I added the output from php -m to my original-post

Comment: I think, there is no missing module. Have you checked `apache2/error.log` for some helpful information?

Comment: @Paul I'm looking the screenshot of your project, after update, and I think that I found the problem. By default PHP 7 doesn't support short open tags `<?` you need to rewrite your code and change them with `<?php`. Or you can try to [**enable short tags option**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) in `php.ini`. Also I've made an experiment. I've run your "test-scrip" on my server and it works. After that I have changed `<?php` with `<?` and I've got blank window.

Comment: I tried to set `short_open_tag=on in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` but for some reason it doesn't works. After that I put `php_flag short_open_tag on` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my-site.conf` - now the page works.

Comment: thank you for this hint, i will carefully check and give feedback this morning.

Comment: If you've solved your question, please move the solution from the question to an answer below.

Comment: I found the reason, why `short_open_tag=on` directive in my `php.in` doesn't work. Just I had it two times and the second was with `off` option. :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED Browser can disply output with following style:

```php
<?  // should be <?php, but it works anyway because 
    $server     = $_SESSION['database_host'];
    $datenbank  = $_SESSION['database_name'];
    $username   = $_SESSION['database_user'];
    $passwort   = $_SESSION['database_user_pw'];
    $mySQL  =  new mysqli($server,$username,$passwort,$datenbank);
    if ($mySQL->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    else
    {
    $sql = "SELECT count(fldID) count from tblPerson";
    // echo"$sql<br>";
    if (!$result = $mySQL->query($sql)) 
    {
        echo "query \"$sql\" failed because $mySQL->error";
        exit;
    }

    if (! $result->num_rows) exit;

    $actor = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $nbr =  $actor['count'];
    echo "nuber is: ".$nbr." persons";

    }
?>
```